# using colored from termcolor with .format in terminal not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to print only 'name','Quiz','Midterm','Final','Average' in red using termcolor but its not working. How can i modify this code to make it work?

```
from termcolor import colored

print(colored('|{:^21}||{:^20}||{:^20}||{:^20}||{ :^20}|'.format('name','Quiz','Midterm','Final','Average','red')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code like this:

```
from termcolor import colored, cprint

cprint(colored('|{:^21}||{:^20}||{:^20}||{:^20}||{:^20}|'
               .format('name', 'Quiz', 'Midterm', 'Final', 'Average'), 'red'))
```

The value "red" should be an argument of the `colored` function, not `format`.

You can also use `cprint` instead of `print`.

Comment: Also fix your format expression: a leading space in the last field. Answer edited.

Comment: This colors the whole string in red including '|','||'. Whereas the problem i have is in coloring only 'name', 'Quiz', 'Midterm', 'Final', 'Average'' in red.